# Changing source of image in long polling HTML/JavaScript & one event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, long-polling

I have a code which requests for image from sever continuously as defined by using pseudo code below.

```
function requestImage(isExternalCall){

    imageDiv.src = "http://webserver/image?Random Generated Link To Prevent Cache"
    if(!isExternalCall){
         imageDiv.one("load", requestImage);
         imageDiv.one("error", requestImage);
         imageDiv.one("abort", requestImage);
    }
}
```

The purpose of this code piece is to poll the server and wait until server renders an image to this request. If any problem occurs or image is loaded successfully, we will request for another one and wait until server renders new one.

The problem is, while we are waiting for an image rendering (while the request status is Pending), we call requestImage function externally to query image with other parameters. Also I am validating that this external call does not attach new onload/onerror/onabort events. Hence, the existing connection is cancelled. Everything is perfect until now.

However, when I count the number of "error events" which are thrown, I observe that there are more than 1 event. Hence, it causes more requestImage callback and eventually a hang in browser because of the request limit. 
According to "one" event description, which can be found in official jquery web site ([link](http://api.jquery.com/one/)), this event should be fired only once.

So, what is wrong according to this logic and design?